# bootstrap popover 3.0 with tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I use bootstrap 3.0 popover with placement: auto right inside tables it doesn't work, and it flows away from the table size.

placement: auto right (means popover should flow to the right if it has a place otherwise flow to the left)

Check this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/65

However, when I place it outside a table it works as it's supposed to be!

```
$('button.hey').popover({
placement: 'auto left',
 html: true,
    //selector: '[rel="popover"]',
    content: function () {
        return "Hi man";
    }
})
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I suggest you to write your own callback for placement rather using 'auto'.

If you want 'right' for your all buttons except last td. Here is how placement can be written

```
$('button.hey').popover({
    placement: function(context,source){
        //check if current td is last one
        var td = $(source).closest('td');
        console.log(td);
        if(td.next().length == 0) {
            return 'left';
        }
        return 'right';
    },
     html: true,
     //selector: '[rel="popover"]',
     content: function () {
        return "Hi man";
     }
})
```

If you want to handle based on position, you can handle that in placement callback.

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/DTcHh/66/

Comment: Thanks man! I would like to give you thumbs up but I don't have 15 points :P once I get it I will give you thumbs up :D